# how to pass date from datepicker in td of table through jquery to mysql

Tags: codeigniter-3

i am working on a project in codeigniter 3. i retrieve data from database in html table in view. there i want to add datepicker in the last cell of table. when i click on the input box in td the datepicker is shown and when i click on the date is selected and shown in input. but i am unable to pass it to td so that i can post it thrugh jquery to the database. when i try to alert the values in each cell of the table, i get something as in td containing datepicker <input type="text" name=dtpicker id = dtpicker. please help to solve my problem

my code in view

```
        <?php if( count($info['porders']) ): ?>
        <?php
        
        $row_count = 1;
        foreach ($info['porders']as $order_info){ ?> 
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_count; ?></td> <!-- Don't remove this column as it's needed for 
        the row commands -->
        <td class="ord_id"><?php print_r($order_info['id']);?></td>
        <td><?php print_r($order_info['name']);?></td>
        
        <td contenteditable="true" class="ord_price"><?php print_r($order_info['price']);?> 
       </td>
        
        <td contenteditable="true" class="ord_qty"><?php print_r($order_info['quantity']);?> 
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"><?php print_r($order_info['company']);?></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="line_total"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="dtpicker" class="datetimepicker" name="dtpicker"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $row_count++; }?>
        </table> 
        </table>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif;?> 
my jquery is
         $("#ordertable").on('click.td', 'td', function() {
         var $td = $(this);
         var text = $(this).html();
         var $input = $('<input class="datetimepicker" value="' + text + '"/>');
         $td.html('').append($input);
         $input.datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
         $td.html(dateText.split('-').reverse().join('/'));
         $td.attr('disabled', false);
         }
         }).datepicker('show');
         });  

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#purchase_btn").click(function(){

        var orderid = $("#number").html();
        var vendorid = $("#ven_id").html();
        var invono  = $("#invo_no").val();
        var date = $("#report_date").val();
        var time = $("#report_time").val();
        var amont = $("#tota").html();


         $.ajax(
         {
          type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url('add_purchase')?>",
            data: {invono:invono,orderid:orderid,vendorid:vendorid,amont:amont},
            success: function(pur_id){
            var purch_id = pur_id;  
            $('#result_report_id_get').html(result);
            var table = document.getElementById('ordertable');
            for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) 
            {
            var arr = [];
            for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            saq=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
            arr.push(saq);
            alert(saq); 
            }
        
            $.ajax(
            {
              type: "POST",
              url:"<?php echo base_url('add_purch_detail')?>",
              data: {purch_id:purch_id,arr:arr},
              success: function(re_id){
              $('#result_report_id_get').html(result);
                // alert(re_id);
              }
              });
              }
              alert("Report is submitted.");
              window.location.reload();
            
              }
              });


               });
               });
```

my controller method is

```
               public function add_purch_detail()
         {  

          $prod_order['purch_id']= $_REQUEST['purch_id'];   
          $order_info=$_REQUEST['arr'];
          $prod_order['productid']=$order_info[1];
          $prod_order['compani']=$order_info[5];
          $prod_order['qty']= $order_info[4];
          $prod_order['amont']= $order_info[6];
          $prod_order['dtp']= $order_info[7];
          $this->purchases->add_purch_detail($prod_order); //
          }
```

what i get in my database is justlike

Edit Copy Delete id   purch_id productid compani qty amont dtp

Edit Copy Delete 172  64       104        0       10 3800   <input class="dateti